# Как можно выделить свои стили в инструменте разработчика в Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Часто для переопределения стилей я использую стандартный инструмент разработчика что есть в Firefox и прямо там прописываю новые правила отображения для элементов, чтобы сразу в браузере видеть результат. Уже затем, вношу такие же изменения в файл со стилями, если удалось получить ожидаемый результат.

Если стилей было добавлено много и у разных классов, то их сложно запомнить.

Есть ли расширения или встроенный в браузер способ по выделению или присвоению меток своим дополнительным стилям?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите `Stylus`

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Действительно, инструмент мне помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте плагин `Stylus`. Он позволит писать `css` для выбранных сайтов.

Например, этот стиль уберет индикатор новичков:

```
/* ==UserStyle==
@name           Stackoverflow new contributor indicator remover
@namespace      github.com/openstyles/stylus
@version        1.0.0
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("*.stackoverflow.com") {
    .new-contributor-indicator {
        display: none;
    }
}
```